# Rivetjs Global onchange event handler

Tags: rivets.js

I'm trying my best to get myself around rivets, but I'm needing to do something that should be simple and I'm not quite sure how to do it.

My case scenario its simple: I have this dataset, and whenever a change occurs either in 'rows' or in a 'row', I need to dispatch this changes right away to the server.

Looks like a common pattern to me, but I can not do it without cheating.

This is my solution so far:

```
var data = {
    rows: [
        {name: 'John', age: 30},
        {name: 'Mary', age: 29}
    ]
}

var self = this
    , valRoutine = rivets.binders['value'].routine;
rivets.binders['value'].routine = function(el, value) {
    var res = valRoutine.call(this, el, value);
    self.doServerStuff(this.model);
    return res;
};
```

How to do event handling in rivets? There is no default events defined? I think that "onModel[add|change|del]Event" should be in the box, am I missing something? Probably am, but the docs dont help much and its not ease to find examples, so... =/

Can anyone help on this?

Ah, by the way, samples on how to put components to work, anyone? It was one of the major reason I came across rivets.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found a much better way:

```
rivets.binders['update'] = {
    bind: function(el) {
        var self    = this
            , field = this.keypath
        ;

        this.callback = function() {
            var page = self.observer.obj;
            if (page.data.main.status == 'editing') {
                var data = {row:{}};
                data[page.key]  = page.data.main.row[page.key];
                data.row[field] = page.data.main.row[field];
                page.exec('update', {
                    data: data
                }, this);
            }
        };

        $(el).on('change', this.callback);
    },

    unbind: function(el) {
        $(el).off('change', this.callback);
    },

    routine: function(el, value) {
    }
};
```

And then, just:

```
<input rv-update="my_field" rv-value="data.row.my_field">
```

I realised that if I catch the update the way I was, at every keystroke it would be calling the server.